# VPN is not connecting after uploading android app bundle(..aab) to play store

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn, ics-openvpn

I am using **ics-openvpn** version 0.7.33 latest one. The app runs fine with .apk. But once I upload to Google play store through .aab then It's not connecting.
After installing the app from the play store, opens fine but on connecting throws exceptions.
Following exceptions are getting...

Error reading from output of OpenVPN process: Cannot run program "/data/app/com.mycompany.sslvpn-VkwWqlSgj-ZP5zBpQLYGNA==**/lib/arm64/libovpnexec.so": error=2,** No such file or directory

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/app/com.mycompany.sslvpn-VkwWqlSgj-ZP5zBpQLYGNA==/lib/arm64/libovpnexec.so": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
    at com.mycompany.sslvpn.core.OpenVPNThread.startOpenVPNThreadArgs(OpenVPNThread.java:123)
    at com.mycompany.sslvpn.core.OpenVPNThread.run(OpenVPNThread.java:65)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

application .apk runs without any exceptions. Exceptions occurred when the app is uploaded to the Play store through the android app bundle(.aab).

I don't know why it's happening.

****Android version: 11,
ics-openvpn version: 0.7.33****

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this just add this line to `gradle.properties`:

```
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs = false
```

Comment: I have also added the following to the main bundle.gradle file. 
android { 

 bundle {
        abi { enableSplit = false }
    }
}

Answer (score 5):

The option setting `'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false'` is deprecated.

The current default is `'true'`

It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You can add the following to your `build.gradle` instead:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = true
        }
    }
}
```